# CoralUI: Children Editor: Event not getting registered or triggered

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

When adding a child component to Tabs/Carosel (or any component that uses common childreneditor), it does add a tab but it does not show up in panel selector dialog box (to give it a name). However it does add the component. To name the tab, one need to close and open editor dialog box again and it shows up.

Debugging it shows that change event is not getting registered/triggered

`selectList.on("coral-selectlist:change" + NS, function(event) {`

This only happens on cloud instances; on local aem cloud sdk; it works as expected. `selectList` element is correct. It does not throw any error on adding the listener; but it does not trigger on `coral-selectlist:change` event

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you find the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Adobe, its been fixed in September 2022 release. At that we had to apply some workaround fix.